Apache Echarts: is a holistic chart available?
I would like to create a chart like this:

I checked the examples: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en but can't find something simular.
Has anyone ever achieved something like this with Echarts? Possibly combine or adjust one of the existing types?

As far as i am not missing something important this could be realized with stacked line series and areaStyle.
Example:
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'stack',
      smooth: true,
      symbol: 'none',
      lineStyle: { color: 'green' },
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'stack',
      smooth: true,
      symbol: 'none',
      lineStyle: { color: 'green' },
      areaStyle: {},
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    }
  ]
};


Example2:
option = {
  grid: {show: true, backgroundColor: '#e6ccb3'},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    nameLocation: 'center',
    nameGap: 25,
    nameTextStyle: {fontSize: 18},
    name: 'WEEKS OF AGE',
    splitLine: {show: true, lineStyle: {width: 2, color: 'white'}},
    minorSplitLine: {show: true, lineStyle: {color: 'white'}},
  },
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      axisLine: {show: true, lineStyle: {width: 3, color: 'blue'}},
      splitLine: {lineStyle: {width: 2, color: 'grey'}},
      minorSplitLine: {show: true, lineStyle: {color: 'white'}}
    },
    {
      type: 'value',
      axisLine: {show: true, lineStyle: {width: 3, color: 'green'}},
      splitLine: {show: false}
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'stack1',
      smooth: true,
      symbolSize: 0,
      lineStyle: {color: 'blue'},
      data: makeData(80, 10)
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'stack1',
      smooth: true,
      symbolSize: 0,
      lineStyle: {color: 'blue'},
      areaStyle: {color: '#5d82ee'},
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: (params) => {if (params.data[0] === 60) {return "name of this series"} else {return ''}}
      },
      data: makeData(80, 10)
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'stack2',
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      smooth: true,
      symbolSize: 0,
      lineStyle: {color: 'green'},
      data: makeData(80, 1400)
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'stack2',
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      smooth: true,
      symbolSize: 0,
      lineStyle: {color: 'green'},
      areaStyle: {color: '#5eba5e'},
      label: {
        show: true,
        formatter: (params) => {if (params.data[0] === 60) {return "name of the other series"} else {return ''}}
      },
      data: makeData(80, 250)
    }
  ]
};


function makeData(numPoints, base) {
  const data = [];
  for (let i=1; i<=numPoints+1; i++) {
    data.push([i, base]);
    base = base + Math.random() * 10;
  }
  return structuredClone(data);
}


Could be something to try. Might be necessary to tweak some things. As this is stacked. In my case it must not be stacked. In some occasions the 'areas' can overlap (see the far right in my image at 1900). I also need two y-axis but that won't be too difficult.

YES! Example 2, That's it. Thank you so much

You will need to use stack, but that just means you need to do some precomputation of your data. I edited the post. I think I got quite close with the second example.
